# Error when installing package from PyPi in R using reticulate and Anaconda3

Tags: python, r, anaconda, reticulate

I am a new user and I'm trying to install a Python package called `capiq_excel` in `R` using `reticulate`. I have anaconda3 as well as S&P Capital IQ's excel plug installed on my system (`capiq_excel` documentation can be found at https://nickderobertis.github.io/capiq-excel-downloader-py/tutorial.html#install)

So far, I've set the path to Python in my R system as follows

```
library(reticulate)

use_python("C:/Users/user/anaconda3/python.exe",
           required = T)

py_config()
```

which provides the following output

```
python:         C:/Users/user/anaconda3/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/user/anaconda3/python38.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/user/anaconda3
version:        3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 17:30:36) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/user/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.18.5

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python function
```

however, when I try to install the `capiq_excel` package using the following line

```
py_install('capiq_excel')
```

I get the following error

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - capiq_excel

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Could this be because the `capiq_excel` package is available on `PyPi` while I'm using an anaconda framework? What is the best way to approach this issue?

TIA!

Comment: ... maybe ... it's `capiq-excel` instead of `capiq_excel`

Comment: @ZhaoYi tried that but that doesn't work. The package's documentation says that it's called ```capiq_excel``` and not ```capiq-excel```

Comment: Have you tried `pip install capiq_excel` directly? I searched this module in conda could and got no result, so it may have not been included by conda.