# How can I install gekko package using R reticulate?

Tags: python, r, anaconda, gekko, reticulate

I can't install gekko package via R reticulate. My R version is 3.4.4 and my Python version is 3.8.8 and I use Gekko in Python without problems. So I tried to install on R in these two ways I know:

1. py_install("gekko")
2. reticulate::conda_install("my_conda_environment", "gekko")

However in both cases I receive the same error bellow.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- gekko

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/root/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/root/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

I didn't find other alternatives in the Anaconda documentation. How can I fix this?

**Edit**: I solved my problem based on the references in John Hedengren's answer and [reticulate docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reticulate/reticulate.pdf). For that, I needed to create a new environment to specify the Python version and packages using the following code in R:

```
reticulate::py_install(
    packages = c(
        "numpy",  
        "pandas", # Or another packages that you need
        "gekko"
    ),
    envname  = "r-gekko",
    method = "conda", # On Windows, the 'conda' method is always used
    python_version = "3.8.8",
    pip = TRUE # It's mandatory to install gekko
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general answer for help in similar cases:

1. Install gekko and other packages in a new environment in R.

```
reticulate::py_install(
    packages = c(
        "gekko",
        "other_package==x.x.x", # It's possible to specify the package version 
        ... 
    ),
    envname = "new_env",
    method = "conda", # For Windows
    python_version = "3.x.x",
    pip = TRUE
)
```

2. Call reticulate package using the new environment.

```
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "/Users/user_name/anaconda#/envs/new_env/python.exe")
library(reticulate)
```

3. Run your Python script with gekko in R.

```
source_python("path/script.py")
```

Answer (score 1):

Gekko is available from pypi.org with `pip install gekko` and is not available with the conda package manager with `conda install gekko`. Here is more information on [how to install Python packages](https://apmonitor.com/pds/index.php/Main/InstallPythonPackages) with `pip`. You likely already know this because you are using `gekko` in Python but I've included it here for some background in case others need it.

Two potential problems are:

- There are multiple Python versions installed and `gekko` is not installed for the version that is used with R.
- Reticulate is not using PyPi repositories to install `gekko`. Here is [additional information](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/python_packages.html) on managing the source (either Conda or PyPi) to retrieve the packages.

I'm not familiar with R but there are others that have similar questions such as:

- [Error when installing package from PyPi in R using reticulate and Anaconda3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64816902/error-when-installing-package-from-pypi-in-r-using-reticulate-and-anaconda3)
- [reticulate conda_install fails to install package from PyPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599049/reticulate-conda-install-fails-to-install-package-from-pypi)
- [Error while installing Python module in R via reticulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67396455/error-while-installing-python-module-in-r-via-reticulate)
- [How to install packages in conda that are not available in anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326043/how-to-install-packages-in-conda-that-are-not-available-in-anaconda)